# Numpy library not resolving in Pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm:

```
PyCharm 2019.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-192.7142.42, built on October 31, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b304.77 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.1
```

And I'm having troubles to import numpy library.

```
import numpy as np
```

Is greyed out and when I run the code nothing happens (Process finished with exit code 0)

I have added numpy to my project's interpreter but it didn't solve the problem

[PyCharm Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QpsU.png)

I have also tried to install numpy with pip command but I'm getting a message that:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.17.4)
```

Has anyone came across similar problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gray import in PyCharm is usually just an import you're not using in your code. If that's the only line of code using `np`, no errors (exit code 0) actually means the import was a success

Hovering over marked code (gray or underlined) with your mouse, will show you what it means

Comment: Good! I overlooked that fact that there was no exception, just grey